# Flutter build ipa obfuscate throws "... unobfuscated DWARF debugging information."

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart

I am getting the error of "**Error (Xcode): Warning: The generated assembly code contains unobfuscated DWARF debugging information.**" when building Flutter with

`flutter build ipa --obfuscate --split-debug-info=<file-path>`

command.

It doesn't throw and builds if I just type

`flutter build ipa` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this command. It works for me.

```
flutter build ipa --target=lib/main.dart --release --obfuscate --split-debug-info=split_debug
```

Here split_debug is path. Version is release, and targets main.dart file for making ipa